# Hadoop job failure : Error Reading IndexFile?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to resolve error like this

```
Map output lost, rescheduling: getMapOutput(attempt_201204251959_0001_m_000000_0,0) failed :
java.io.IOException: Error Reading IndexFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache.readIndexFileToCache(IndexCache.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache.getIndexInformation(IndexCache.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$MapOutputServlet.doGet(TaskTracker.java:3745)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:818)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Owner '4294967294' for path /work/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201204251959_0001/attempt_201204251959_0001_m_000000_0/output/file.out.index did not match expected owner 'hduser'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.checkStat(SecureIOUtils.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openForRead(SecureIOUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache.readIndexFileToCache(IndexCache.java:109)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2389.
Looks like using another jetty version could help...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but still, for someone who may encounter the same problem again :

Hadoop v1.2.1 comes with Jetty v6.1.26.
I had this same problem while running Hadoop on Java7 (openJDK).

The problem was solved while running hadoop on Java6. There is probably a compatiblity issue across Java versions.